# Is it possible to factor a huge matrix (SVD or NMF) without never computing it?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, computational-mathematics

I have a linear function $u$ from approximately $\mathbb{R}^{10^6} \to \mathbb{R}^{3\times10^5}$.
It has a certain computing cost so I would like to approximate it using a factored matrix représentation. This could be by using the first $k$ component of its SVD (Singular Value Decomposition), or by using a Non Negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) of small rank $k$.

Since the input and output dimension are really huge, it is not possible to actually compute or store the whole matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that would be associated to this linear function.

So my question is: is there a way to actually compute a factored representation (which does not need terabytes of storage) of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ without ever storing this huge matrix, but by relying only on several evaluations of $u$?

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does this function do?

Comment: It's a ray tracer which, under certain conditions, is linear (and non negative).

Comment: Without the ability to compute $y = A^Tx$ for any $x$ there is very little that can be done subject to your restrictions. Do you have this ability or not? If yes, then it is easy to answer your question. If no, then your question becomes a research problem.

Comment: Indeed I don't think I can evaluate the transposed matrix at some points